# Python Object Oriented Programming

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, class, oop

I have to write a program to demonstrate a customer using their credit card to check out, I have spent a few hours trying to figure out how to do it and have provided my code below.

I have to make a class, then use it in a main function.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Customer:

    def __init__(self, customer_name, credit_card_num, credit_security_code, debit_card_num, debit_pin):
        self.customer_name = name
        self.credit_card_num = credit_num
        self.credit_security_code = credit_code
        self.debit_card_num = debit_num
        self.debit_pin = debit_pin


    def inputCardInfo(self):
        self.customer_name = str(input("Enter your name: "))
        self.credit_card_num = str(input("Enter credit card Number: "))
        self.credit_security_code = str(input("Enter 3-digit security code: "))
        self.debit_card_num = str(input("Enter debit card number: "))
        self.debit_pin = str(input("Enter 4-digit PIN: "))
```

then the main function:

```
from customer import Customer

def main():
    print("Welcome to Wake-Mart. Please register.")
    customer_name = input("enter name: ")
    customer1 = Customer(customer_name)
    print("Registration completed")

main()
```

I don't know the correct way to call the class methods. I feel if I can figure out how to make one of these work I can figure out the rest.

Comment: Please read [OOP in Python](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/object_oriented_programming.html). You will be able to solve your problem by own

Comment: What have you tried? Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand behaviors and properties more deeply I would recommend making a separate behavior for each value. (get_credit_num, get_debit_num, etc.)
Then, in your main, just call each function individually to get each value.

And to clarify, "class functions", or behaviors, are just things an object can do. You call them the same way you would any function, with the only difference being you put the name of the instance you are calling this behavior for before the function to replace "self". So if you were calling "InputCardInfo" for the object customer1, you would do it like so:

```
customer1.InputCardInfo(other parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code as-is will not work because you are not passing all required parameters when initializing your class.

> `customer1 = Customer(customer_name)`

All of the additional parameters besides `self` included in your `def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):` needs to be passed to the class instance when initializing. There are also variable naming issues with your code but I hope my example below clarifies things for you.

**A quick note first to help you better understand**: `self.customer_name = name` does not make sense in your code because there is no parameter named `name` included in the `__init__()` method. You must associate an instance variable (`self.whatever`) to a known variable name passed in through the `__init__(self, external_var)` method so that `self.whatever = external_var`. Then, and only then, can you use class methods to call `self.whatever` and expect to receive the data you passed from `external_var`. Also, additional parameters you include after `self` in `__init__(self, ..., ...)` MUST be passed as variables when creating a class instance.

```
class Customer:

    def __init__(self, customer_name, credit_card_num, credit_security_code, debit_card_num, debit_pin):
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.credit_card_num = credit_card_num
        self.credit_security_code = credit_security_code
        self.debit_card_num = debit_card_num
        self.debit_pin = debit_pin


name = 'Mike'
cc_num = '0000 0000 0000 0000'
code = '111'
debit_num = '1111 1111 1111 1111'
pin = '1234'

new_customer = Customer(name, cc_num, code, debit_num, pin)
```